# PHP include runs when in short tags even when short tags are turned off

Tags: php

> **NOTE:**
>   This question is NOT about using short tags in PHP. The issue is not the short tags themselves but the way that `include` functions seem to ignore the disabled status of short tags on this Plesk server.

I have a new site to take care of and fix up. The site was built by another, and was built many years ago using non-best practise. The site has recently been moved to a Plesk Server.

I am unfamiliar with Plesk and so have been learning it's routines.

## My issue is:

A core setting on the Plesk PHP setup is that short tags ( `<? ... ?>`) are disabled. The site I'm working on makes extensive use of short tags (as well as full `<?php` tags).

The issue is the code within the short tags the PHP `include` function still executes and loads, and its contents still outputs to the browser source HTML, but anything else in the short tags does not execute.

## WHY does this happen?

- Is this a Plesk issue?
- Is this a bug with `include`?

---

## Server Settings:

- Plesk Onyx (I can't find a version number)
- PHP 5.6.31 (handler: FPM application)
- PHP ini (loaded from the site directly):  `short_open_tag:   Off`
- Included PHP files use both full tags and short tags with the same outcome.

## The code I have:

The **HTML** Page (`index.php`, various pages):

```
<?
session_start();
include "inc/dbi.php";
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $id = substr($_REQUEST['id'],0,6);
}
else{
    header("Location: index.php?msg=No image specified");
    exit;
    }
$qry        = mysqli_query($MySQlink,"...");
$row        = mysqli_fetch_array($qry);
$docwidth   = floor($row['width']*4.26);
$docwidth  /= 100;
$docheight  = floor($row['height']*04.26);
$docheight /= 100;
$descr      = nl2br($descr);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
...
...
```

The **inc/dbi.php** page:

```
<?php
$user     = "some_user";
$pass     = "some_pass";
$db       = "some_db";
$MySQlink = mysqli_connect( "localhost" , $user, $pass, $db );
if ( ! $MySQlink )  {   mysqli_close($MySQlink);    }
$now      = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');    
$today    = date('Y-m-d ');
```

---

## What I expect to see in source code of HTML file:

```
<?
session_start();
include "inc/dbi.php";
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $id = substr($_REQUEST['id'],0,6);
}
else{
    header("Location: index.php?msg=No image specified");
    exit;
    }
$qry        = mysqli_query($MySQlink,"...");
$row        = mysqli_fetch_array($qry);
$docwidth   = floor($row['width']*4.26);
$docwidth  /= 100;
$docheight  = floor($row['height']*04.26);
$docheight /= 100;
$descr      = nl2br($descr);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

## What I actually see:

```
<?
session_start();
$user     = "some_user";
$pass     = "some_pass";
$db       = "some_db";
$MySQlink = mysqli_connect( "localhost" , $user, $pass, $db );
if ( ! $MySQlink )  {   mysqli_close($MySQlink);    }
$now      = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');    
$today    = date('Y-m-d '); 

if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $id = substr($_REQUEST['id'],0,6);
}
else{
    header("Location: index.php?msg=No image specified");
    exit;
    }
$qry        = mysqli_query($MySQlink,"...");
$row        = mysqli_fetch_array($qry);
$docwidth   = floor($row['width']*4.26);
$docwidth  /= 100;
$docheight  = floor($row['height']*04.26);
$docheight /= 100;
$descr      = nl2br($descr);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

## Please note:

I am well aware of the short-coming of the above code, but it's not my work and it is my job to fix these shortcomings and make it [much] better.

*But*, I am confused by the behaviour of the include function, and have already read [various](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41741) PHP bug reports as well as reading up the manual for [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and [PHP.ini short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). none of which mentions this issue.

---

My chief concern is that for some period of time Database connection details were output to the HTML (and have since been changed, obviously).

Comment: @Martin aww sucks, I've spent many hours looking into php config to find I was in the wrong ini file haha ok well at least thats crossed off :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs but the PHP.ini status is not that important; if short tags where enabled then nothing would be output to the HTML source, if they're disabled then everything would be output and that should include the `include` statement without it being processed and loaded.

Comment: @Martin ah yeah suppose that's true! maybe try swapping out the include to require_once? see if that makes a difference :)

Comment: @Martin why not convert short tags to full tags as step 1 of any fix?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone that is curing the symptom not the underlying issue. The issue is that in `<?` tags some code seems to still work as PHP whilst other code is ignored. I'm well aware of the preference for removing short tags but that deosn't really relate to the observed issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce this right now, or is this something that you saw once?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs `require` exhibits the same behaviour. the contents of the required file are still output.

Comment: @MattGibson this is current.

Comment: It feels like there must be something else going on. What is the filename (or just extension) of the "HTML" file in your example? And could something other than PHP be set up to process it? (i.e. we may need to find out how the web server is processing the files right from start to finish, not just the PHP handler...)

Comment: @MattGibson I suspect it's some sort of auto- output buffering (`ob_`) functionality that Plesk inserts between the page running and the browser loading it, but that's only a suspicion as yet.

Comment: I have raised a request flag with Plesk to ask them what pre-processing they carry out on PHP files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The included files are not read on the compilation phase but during runtime.**

Since your PHP interpreter doesn't interpret the code in short tags and dumps it directly to the browser, it is not guilty for replacing the `include` statements with the content of the included files.
There is no `php.ini` setting that could persuade it to behave like this.

I can imagine other causes:

- a PHP extension that replaces the `include/require` statements with the content of the included files;
- a pre-processing script that does the same and/or combines multiple PHP files into a single one (Symfony does something similar);

The purpose of such a processing is to optimize the script by minimizing its disk access.

Comment: Well, yeah, these were the lines I was thinking along, but it would be nice to know exactly what was causing it. The existing codebase doesn't seem "clever" enough to be using a solution like that deliberately :D

Comment: I suspect it's something on the Plesk trying to do something like this, but as stated in the question, I'm not familiar enough with Plesk to be sure.  I suspect it's some sort of auto- output buffering (`ob_`) functionality that Plesk inserts between the page running and the browser loading it, but that's only a suspicion as yet.

Comment: It's not output buffering. Since you receive it in the browser it's clear that the PHP code doesn't run. It doesn't `session_start()` and it doesn't `include` anything. It doesn't even touch the `"inc/dbi.php"` file. It's something else, outside of the normal flow of the PHP script. Either a PHP extension that ignores the `short_open_tag` setting or an external tool that also doesn't know or doesn't care how the PHP interpreter is configured. And it operates before the script is loaded or, if it's a PHP extension, during the compilation phase.

Comment: Cheers for your help. Plesk Helpdesk got back to me, my own answer details their response. Overall they seemed caging and unwilling to detail their PHP processing process.

Answer (score 0):

Plesk help were, er, unhelpful and the responder didn't have an immediate answer to my issue.

Overall they seemed cagey and unwilling to detail their PHP processing process. They simply said that they run all PHP scripts through their standard Plesk security extensions.

This didn't tell me a whole lot but the Plesk responder did offer to re-enable short tags on the account (I do not have admin privilages on the account and only have an entry or reseller level access on he account so can't edit the core account php.ini myself).

re-enabling short tags obviously solves the concern of outputting PHP details to the browser.

I assume that there is something Plesk is doing similar to [as described by axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45843674/3536236) so am marking his/her answer as correct; although it doesn't solve the issue in this case, it does (most probably) seem to identify it.

Comment: Unfortunately, their "standard security extensions" in this case work in reverse and reveal the information they should protect :-(

Comment: While enabling the short open tags solved your immediate problem, the best way on long term is to replace the short open tags with [complete open tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php). The [short open tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) are disabled by default on a fresh PHP installation and you should expect to encounter issues with them again if you change the hosting again. The tag `<?=` (which is the short form of `<?php echo`) is not affected by `short_open_tag` (since PHP 5.4). You can keep it in the code if it is used.

Comment: @axiac oh yes I am well aware of the status of short tags and it's part of my work to transition the whole site to proper `<?php` tags, but the behaviour encoutered was/is very curious.